# Why is PG::ConnectionBad error not being caught in my Rails middleware rescue block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm developing a Rails 6 application that includes a custom middleware called PGConnectionErrorMiddleware. This middleware is responsible for catching PG::ConnectionBad exceptions and returning a custom response when they occur.

However, I've noticed that the middleware isn't behaving as expected. Even when a PG::ConnectionBad exception is raised, the rescue block in the middleware isn't catching the exception. Instead, the application returns a 500 error, which is not what I want.

I've spent some time trying to figure out what's causing the problem, but I haven't been able to make any progress. I'm not sure if there's a problem with my middleware code or if there's some other issue that I'm not aware of.

Here's the relevant code in my middleware (lib/pg_connection_error_middleware.rb):

```
class PGConnectionErrorMiddleware
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end
  
    def call(env)
      puts "PGConnectionErrorMiddleware called!" 
      status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
      puts "Status code: #{status}"
      puts "Headers: #{headers.inspect}"
      [status, headers, response]
    rescue => e
      Rails.logger.error "PG::ConnectionBad: #{e.message}"
      puts "PG::ConnectionBad>>: #{e.message}"
      [503, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }, [File.read(Rails.public_path.join('503.html'))]]
    end
  end
```

And here's the relevant portion of the logs when the exception occurs:

```
PGConnectionErrorMiddleware called!
Started GET "/sign_in" for 172.19.0.1 at 2023-02-26 20:27:51 +0000
PGConnectionErrorMiddleware called!
Started GET "/tour" for 172.19.0.1 at 2023-02-26 20:28:10 +0000
  
PG::ConnectionBad (could not translate host name "postgresql" to address: Name or service not known
):
  
lib/pg_connection_error_middleware.rb:8:in `call'
Status code: 500
Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=UTF-8", "Content-Length"=>"728", "X-Request-Id"=>"03b35a89-1de9-4d82-a5ab-039b5fe45ef1", "X-Runtime"=>"18.744346"}
  
PG::ConnectionBad (could not translate host name "postgresql" to address: Name or service not known
):
  
lib/pg_connection_error_middleware.rb:8:in `call'
Status code: 500
Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=UTF-8", "Content-Length"=>"728", "X-Request-Id"=>"fb4be3c4-5d8e-4503-980c-73a898d96933", "X-Runtime"=>"67.208042"}
```

As you can see, the middleware is called `(PGConnectionErrorMiddleware called!)` and the exception is raised, but it's not being caught by the rescue block, and instead a 500 error is returned. How can I modify the middleware to correctly catch the exception and return the custom response in my rescue block?

Update:
I managed to get it to work with the following code.

```
class PGConnectionErrorMiddleware
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end
  
    def call(env)
      begin
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection
        @app.call(env)
      rescue PG::ConnectionBad => e
        Rails.logger.error "PG::ConnectionBad: #{e.message}"
        [503, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }, [File.read(Rails.public_path.join('503.html'))]]
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: I think whats going on here is that that [`ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/ShowExceptions.html) is rescueing the exception further down in the Rack middleware stack so it never reaches your middleware. You can avoid your workaround by inserting your middleware after it. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#adding-a-middleware